# Multiple materials do not work

Tags: materials, uv, node-editor

I have multiple materials assigned to my object. When I choose them in the shading tab, the other one goes away. The model is UV-unwrapped and the materials are assigned to the correct places.

Comment: Hi, please add images to illustrate your question.

Comment: This is intended behavior. You have to select the wanted material slot (just on the left of the material selection).